# perl regex problem -- $amp in yahoo finance page

Tags: regex, perl

I found an old perl hack on the O'Reilly site http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1041 and decided to check it out. After a little fiddling around it started to run but the regex are out of date.
Here is the question: with this

```
  /<a href="\/q\/op\?s=(.*?)\&m=(.*?)">/
```

as the first line of  regex, what needs to be modified to make the regex function again? The following are snippets from

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=FISV

```
 <a href="/q/op?s=FISV&amp;k=55.000000">
```

and

```
 <a href="/q/os?s=FISV&amp;m=2011-04-15">
```

.

The original hack is dated 2004 and option symbols looked like this (FQVAH or FQVFF) back then instead  of fisv110416c00060000 for a call option and fisv110416p00090000 for a put option. First thing I did to get it going was to modify all instances of $url to $curl because until the name was changed the symbol was not being passed to yahoo for lookup. The &amp is giving me the most trouble. If this is found to run without modification I would be very surprised and would very much like to know what system and perl -V is installed. SLES 10 and perl 5.8.0 is what I am currently using.

Any suggestions would be helpful. It could be a useful script to anyone who is serious about protecting themselves from a falling equity market.

Thanks,

robm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not /100%/ sure what you're asking, but if I'm understanding, you want a regex that will capture "fisv110416c00060000" and tell you the first few letters, whether it's a call or a put, and the amount?

If so, you're looking for something like:

```
/([a-z]+)(\d+)([cp])(\d+)/
```

That should capture the following for the first example

```
$1 = "fisv"
$2 = 110416
$3 = c
$4 = 00060000
```

The original regex was very specific to that html string. You can include the beginning bits of it if you need to use it to check that the entire string is there as well. Of course, make your regex as tight as possible to avoid over-matches and wasted time pattern matching. I'm just not sure the exact pattern you're trying to match (ie: is it always "fisv"?).

Answer (score 1):

You should either first unescape the html, this would turn the `&amp;` into a `&`, or just change the regex, like this:

```
/<a href="\/q\/os\?s=(.*?)\&(?:amp;)?m=(.*?)">/
```

To match both types of urls:

```
/<a href="\/q\/o[ps]\?s=(.*?)\&(?:amp;)?[mk]=(.*?)">/
```